# Shape Detection using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I would like to **detect shapes** namely circle, square, rectangle, triangle, etc., using **Machine Learning** Techniques.

Following are the specifications for shape detection,

1. Convolutional Neural Network ( CNN ) is used.
2. For Training, Dataset contains 1000 images in each category for 10 shapes.
3. For Testing, Dataset contains 100 images in each category for 10 shapes.
4. All images are 28x28 resize with one channel ( gray channel ).
5. All the images in the dataset are edge-detected images.

**Questions**

1. Is it possible for the machine learning algorithm to differentiate between a square and a rectangle...?, square and a rhombus...?
2. How can i improve the dataset for shape detection ?
   Thanks in Advance...!!!

Comment: This question is more suited for the [data science stack exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). Your problem is similar to the [digit recognition problem](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer) and I can't see a reason why it would not be possible to do such thing, given you have a big enough dataset of pictures of shapes labelled.

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. You can make sure the shapes are centred, and normalised to [0, 1] range. Maybe some thresholding. One would really have to see the data to tell you what exactly you can do. You have not included even a single image..

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, and it is not a very hard task for a CNN to do.
2. One way to improve the dataset is to use image augmentation. I think you can do both horizontal and vertical flips as all these figures are still the same kind of figures when applying this transformation. You can think of other transformations as long as they don't change the axes sizes, because if you change the sizes of the axes a square becomes a rectangle, and viceversa.